# Query Group Feed Posts by `created_time`

Tags: facebook-graph-api

For a small Facebook Sales Group Monitor I need to query the group's new posts. I've intended to do this via the Graph API, requesting only posts which have been either

- created since the last query (`created_time`) or
- updated since the last query (`updated_time`).

This, however, seems not to be possible.

Omitting all non-date fields, a `GET /v2.7/<group-id>/feed` request returns the following data:

```
"data": [
  {
    "updated_time": "2016-01-12T20:11:02+0000",
    "created_time": "2014-09-16T09:55:39+0000",
    "id": "552364968142715_789142084465001"
  },
  {
    "updated_time": "1970-01-01T00:16:40+0000",
    "created_time": "2016-08-28T19:15:53+0000",
    "id": "552364968142715_1183108935068312"
  },
  {
    "updated_time": "1970-01-01T00:16:39+0000",
    "created_time": "2016-08-29T14:13:22+0000",
    "id": "552364968142715_1183722648340274"
  },
  {
    "updated_time": "1970-01-01T00:16:38+0000",
    "created_time": "2016-08-28T09:15:05+0000",
    "id": "552364968142715_1182673285111877"
  },
  ...
]
```

- The first entry is from the pinned group-rules post, created in 2014, updated 2016.
- The second and fourth entries are both from yesterday, the third post is from today.
- All but the first post have `updated_time`-timestamps close to the UNIX epoch's beginning. With a few exceptions, the value seems to be decreasing by 1 second for every post in the list, *even when requesting 100+ posts*.

The [API Reference for Group feeds](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/group/feed#read) states, that the `since=<timestamp>` query parameter only applies on the `updated_time` field, which does not help in this case.

**Is there any way to filter for or at least sort by the `created_time` value?**

Answer (score 0):

I am running into same problem. It seems currently `created_time` only apply for Page feed, not Group feed at the moment :(